# JQuery Dialog won't enable changing data in text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have project that shows few tables and try to use JQuery dialog boxes to change and add data to tables. 
I implemented dialog and the function to show it and populate with content from table works fine. Also save button works nice so I save content to database.

My question is when I open dialog my content inside text boxes is not editable. I puted input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="codice" id="codice" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" contenteditable="true" />
```

Can anyone help me to enalbe editing to those fields.
Thanks.

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Gestione Tipo Appuntamento" >
    <form id="dialogform" action="agendaTipoAppuntamentoSalvaJson.do" contenteditable="true" >
    <input type="hidden" name="idTipoAppuntamento" id="idTipoAppuntamento" value=""  />
    <fieldset><table>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="codice">Codice </label>
        </td><td>
        <input type="text" name="codice" id="codice" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" contenteditable="true" />
        </td></tr><tr>
        <td>
        <label for="descrizione">Descrizione </label>
        </td><td>
        <input type="text" name="descrizione" id="descrizione" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" contenteditable="true" />
        </td></tr><tr>
        <td>
        <label for="descrBreve">descrBreve </label>
        </td><td>
        <input type="text" name="descrBreve" id="descrBreve" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" contenteditable="true" />
        </td></tr><tr>
        <td>
        <label for="colore">colore </label>
        </td><td>
        <input type="text" name="colore" id="colore" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" contenteditable="true" />
        </td>
        </tr>

    </table></fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

and JS part to call variables:

```
function showUpdate(id,codice,descrizione,descrBreve,colore) {

        $('#idTipoAppuntamento').val(id); 
        $('#codice').val(codice);              
        $('#descrizione').val(descrizione);
        $('#descrBreve').val(descrBreve);
        $('#colore').val(colore);
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole div that is the dialog ? how do you initialize the contents of the inputs ?

Comment: It's a bug. I found solution to put position: relative; z-index: 9999; into style for div that holds form and everything work now...

Comment: Can you add it as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. I found solution to put:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
```

into style for div that holds form and everything work now...

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful to me. What a bizarre behavior. The input could still get focus and triggered keyup events, but somehow the z-index didn't allow anything to be in it.